# How to get only mismatched results from comparing 2 columns in the same table

Tags: sql, ssms

I have 2 columns in 1 table that I need to compare for mismatches. i.e. Column A does not match what is in Column B. I would also like to only see the mismatched results.

```
select K,pbs#ID,PBS#disp, ln#id, ln#disp
from dbo.book7
where ln#disp is not null and pbs#disp is not null
```

I would like to see just the results if the columns pbs#disp and ln#disp do not match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have to show some examples, but have you tried:

```sql
    select K,pbs#ID,PBS#disp, ln#id, ln#disp
    from dbo.book7
    where ln#disp is not null and pbs#disp is not null
    AND  pbs#disp <> ln#disp
```